# Converting json to a graphene graphql response

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, graphql, graphene-python

I am using [graphene](http://graphene-python.org/) and flask to create a graphql server. I have a query that is quite expensive and would like to cache it. Currently I manually execute the schema to get a JSON result, which I then persist in a database. I think I can intercept the query in a middleware, but not sure **how to convert the JSON I have into a format graphene knows how to handle**.

Answer (score 3):

I used a solution found in this site: https://www.codementor.io/nikolayderkach/how-to-build-a-graphql-wrapper-for-a-restful-api-in-python-e7w68kcav

```
import json
from collections import namedtuple

def _json_object_hook(d):
    return namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values())

def json2obj(data):
    return json.loads(data, object_hook=_json_object_hook)

...

class Foo(graphene.ObjectType):
    something = ...

    def resolve_something(self, info):
        ...
        return json2obj(json.dumps(your_json_object))
```